# If $Z^-$ is a generalized inverse of $Z=KAK$, and $K$ is idempotent, then $KZ^-K$ is also a generalized inverse of $Z$.

Tags: matrices

If $Z^-$ is a generalized inverse of $Z=KAK$, and $K$ is idempotent, then $KZ^-K$ is also a generalized inverse of $Z$.

What I have so far doesn't use the fact that $K$ is idempotent, so I don't think it's correct:

Since $Z^-$ is a generalized inverse of $Z=KAK$, then $A=Z^-$

$$Z=KAK$$
$$ZK^-=KA$$
$$K^-ZK^-=A$$

Then $K^-ZK^-=A=Z^-$

And since $Z^-$ is a generalized inverse of $Z$, then $K^-ZK^-$ is also a generalized inverse of $Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(KZ^-K)$ to be a generalized inverse of $Z$, it must satisfy

$$Z(KZ^-K)Z = Z$$
Inserting $Z= KAK$ in the LHS we have

$$Z(KZ^-K)Z = KAK(KZ^-K)KAK =  KAKZ^-KAK $$

since $K$ is idempoptent

$$\Rightarrow (KAK)Z^-(KAK)= ZZ^-  Z=Z$$

since $Z^-$ is by assumption a generalized inverse of $Z$. So the basic condition for a matrix to be a generalized inverse holds.